# compare case class fields with sub fields of another case class in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following 3 case classes:

```
case class Profile(name: String,
                   age: Int,
                   bankInfoData: BankInfoData,
                   userUpdatedFields: Option[UserUpdatedFields])

case class BankInfoData(accountNumber: Int,
                        bankAddress: String,
                        bankNumber: Int,
                        contactPerson: String,
                        phoneNumber: Int,
                        accountType: AccountType)

case class UserUpdatedFields(contactPerson: String,
                             phoneNumber: Int,
                             accountType: AccountType)
```

this is just enums, but i added anyway:

```
sealed trait AccountType extends EnumEntry

object AccountType extends Enum[AccountType] {
  val values: IndexedSeq[AccountType] = findValues

  case object Personal extends AccountType

  case object Business extends AccountType

}
```

my task is - i need to write a funcc `Profile` and compare UserUpdatedFields(all of the fields) with SOME of the fields in BankInfoData...this func is to find which fields where updated.

so I wrote this func:

```
def findDiff(profile: Profile): Seq[String] = {
  var listOfFieldsThatChanged: List[String] = List.empty
  if (profile.bankInfoData.contactPerson != profile.userUpdatedFields.get.contactPerson){
    listOfFieldsThatChanged = listOfFieldsThatChanged :+ "contactPerson"
  }
  if (profile.bankInfoData.phoneNumber != profile.userUpdatedFields.get.phoneNumber) {
    listOfFieldsThatChanged = listOfFieldsThatChanged :+ "phoneNumber"
  }
  if (profile.bankInfoData.accountType != profile.userUpdatedFields.get.accountType) {
    listOfFieldsThatChanged = listOfFieldsThatChanged :+ "accountType"
  }
  listOfFieldsThatChanged
}

val profile =
  Profile(
    "nir",
    34,
    BankInfoData(1, "somewhere", 2, "john", 123, AccountType.Personal),
    Some(UserUpdatedFields("lee", 321, AccountType.Personal))
  )

findDiff(profile)
```

it works, but wanted something cleaner..any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Each case class extends [Product](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Product.html) interface so we could use it to convert case classes into sets of (field, value) elements. Then we can use set operations to find the difference. For example,

```
  def findDiff(profile: Profile): Seq[String] = {
    val userUpdatedFields = profile.userUpdatedFields.get
    val bankInfoData = profile.bankInfoData

    val updatedFieldsMap = userUpdatedFields.productElementNames.zip(userUpdatedFields.productIterator).toMap
    val bankInfoDataMap = bankInfoData.productElementNames.zip(bankInfoData.productIterator).toMap
    val bankInfoDataSubsetMap = bankInfoDataMap.view.filterKeys(userUpdatedFieldsMap.keys.toList.contains)
    (bankInfoDataSubsetMap.toSet diff updatedFieldsMap.toSet).toList.map { case (field, value) => field }
  }
```

Now `findDiff(profile)` should output `List(phoneNumber, contactPerson)`. Note we are using [productElementNames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600495/5205022) from Scala 2.13 to get the filed names which we then zip with corresponding values

```
userUpdatedFields.productElementNames.zip(userUpdatedFields.productIterator)
```

Also we rely on [filterKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147203/5205022) and [diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24837326/5205022).

Answer (score 3):

A simple improvement would be to introduce a trait

```
trait Fields {
  val contactPerson: String
  val phoneNumber: Int
  val accountType: AccountType

  def findDiff(that: Fields): Seq[String] = Seq(
    Some(contactPerson).filter(_ != that.contactPerson).map(_ => "contactPerson"),
    Some(phoneNumber).filter(_ != that.phoneNumber).map(_ => "phoneNumber"),
    Some(accountType).filter(_ != that.accountType).map(_ => "accountType")
  ).flatten
}

case class BankInfoData(accountNumber: Int,
                          bankAddress: String,
                          bankNumber: Int,
                          contactPerson: String,
                          phoneNumber: Int,
                          accountType: String) extends Fields

case class UserUpdatedFields(contactPerson: String,
                           phoneNumber: Int,
                           accountType: AccountType) extends Fields
```

so it was possible to call

```
BankInfoData(...). findDiff(UserUpdatedFields(...))
```

If you want to further-improve and avoid naming all the fields multiple times, for example shapeless could be used to do it compile time. Not exactly the same but something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434302/extract-label-values-from-a-labelledgeneric-instance) to get started. Or use reflection to do it runtime like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079113/scala-2-10-reflection-how-do-i-extract-the-field-values-from-a-case-class-i-e).

Comment: thing is also that i dont want to extend my case classes with Fields, since its only a small case of the whole app that uses those case classes...and another thing is that in UserUpdatedFields i have a field that is actually Option,  phoneNumber is Option[Int] and in BankInfoData is just Int.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a very easy task to achieve if it would be an easy way to convert case class to map. Unfortunately, case classes don't offer that functionality out-of-box yet in Scala 2.12 (as Mario have mentioned it will be easy to achieve in Scala 2.13).

There's a library called [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), that offers some generic programming utilities. For example, we could write an extension function `toMap` using `Record` and `ToMap` from shapeless:

```
object Mappable {
  implicit class RichCaseClass[X](val x: X) extends AnyVal {
    import shapeless._
    import ops.record._

    def toMap[L <: HList](
        implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[X, L],
        toMap: ToMap[L]
    ): Map[String, Any] =
      toMap(gen.to(x)).map{
        case (k: Symbol, v) => k.name -> v
      }
    }
}
```

Then we could use it for `findDiff`:

```
def findDiff(profile: Profile): Seq[String] = {
  import Mappable._

  profile match {
    case Profile(_, _, bankInfo, Some(userUpdatedFields)) =>
      val bankInfoMap = bankInfo.toMap
      userUpdatedFields.toMap.toList.flatMap{
        case (k, v) if bankInfoMap.get(k).exists(_ != v) => Some(k)
        case _ => None
      }
    case _ => Seq()
  }
}
```